# Iterating through csv records based on the version of the record via Python

Tags: python

I have a csv file that has a primary_id field and a version field and it looks like this:

```
ful_id                               version    xs  at_grade    date
000c1a6c-1f1c-45a6-a70d-f3555f7dd980    3       123   yes      20171003
000c1a6c-1f1c-45a6-a70d-f3555f7dd980    1       12    no       20170206
034c1a6c-4f1c-aa36-a70d-f2245f7rr342    1       334   yes      20150302
00dc5fec-ddb8-45fa-9c86-77e09ff590a9    1       556   yes      20170201
000c1a6c-1f1c-45a6-a70d-f3555f7dd980    2       123   no       20170206
```

*edit this is what the actual data looks like plus add 106 more columns of data and 20,000 records*

The larger version number is the latest version of that record.I am having a difficult time thinking of the logic to get the latest record based on version and dumping that into a dictionary.I am pulling the info from the csv into a blank list but If anyone could give me some guidance on some of the logic moving forward, I would appreciate it

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

reader = csv.DictReader(open('rpm_inv.csv', 'rb'))
allData = list(reader)
dict_list = []
for line in allData:
   dict_list.append(line)
pprint.pprint(dict_list)
```

Comment: You need `groupby`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for anything fancy.

- `defaultdict` is included in Python's standard library. It's an improved dictionary. I've used it here because it obviates the need to initialise entries in a dictionary. This means that I can write, for instance, `result[id] = max(result[id], version)`. If no entry exists for `id` then `defaultdict` creates one and puts `version` in it (because it's obvious that this will be the maximum).
- I read through the lines  in the input file, one at a time, discarding end-lines and blanks, splitting on the commas, and then use `map` to apply the `int` function to each string produced.
- I ignore the first line in the file simply be reading it and assigning its contents to a variable that I have arbitrarily called `ignore`.
- Finally, just to make the results more intelligible, I sort the keys in the dictionary, and present the contents of it in order.

---

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> result = defaultdict(int)
>>> with open('to_dict.txt') as input:
...     ignore = input.readline()
...     for line in input:
...         id, version = map(int, line.strip().replace(' ', '').split(','))
...         result[id] = max(result[id], version)
...         

>>> ids = list(result.keys())
>>> ids.sort()
>>> for id in ids:
...     id, result[id]
...     
(3, 1)
(11, 3)
(20, 2)
(400, 2)
```

**EDIT**: With that much data it becomes a different question, in my estimation, better processed with pandas.

I've put the `df.groupby(['ful_id']).version.idxmax()` bit in to demonstrate what I've done. I group on `ful_id`, then ask for the maximum value of `version` and the index of the maximum value, all in one step using `idxmax`. Although pandas displays this as a two-column table the result is actually a list of integers that I can use to select rows from the dataframe.

That's what I do with `df.iloc[df.groupby(['ful_id']).version.idxmax(),:]`. Here the `df.groupby(['ful_id']).version.idxmax()` part identifies the rows, and the `:` part identifies the columns, namely all of them.

Thanks for an interesting question!

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('different.csv', sep='\s+')
>>> df
                                 ful_id  version   xs at_grade      date
0  000c1a6c-1f1c-45a6-a70d-f3555f7dd980        3  123      yes  20171003
1  000c1a6c-1f1c-45a6-a70d-f3555f7dd980        1   12       no  20170206
2  034c1a6c-4f1c-aa36-a70d-f2245f7rr342        1  334      yes  20150302
3  00dc5fec-ddb8-45fa-9c86-77e09ff590a9        1  556      yes  20170201
4  000c1a6c-1f1c-45a6-a70d-f3555f7dd980        2  123       no  20170206
>>> df.groupby(['ful_id']).version.idxmax()
ful_id
000c1a6c-1f1c-45a6-a70d-f3555f7dd980    0
00dc5fec-ddb8-45fa-9c86-77e09ff590a9    3
034c1a6c-4f1c-aa36-a70d-f2245f7rr342    2
Name: version, dtype: int64
>>> new_df = df.iloc[df.groupby(['ful_id']).version.idxmax(),:]
>>> new_df
                                 ful_id  version   xs at_grade      date
0  000c1a6c-1f1c-45a6-a70d-f3555f7dd980        3  123      yes  20171003
3  00dc5fec-ddb8-45fa-9c86-77e09ff590a9        1  556      yes  20170201
2  034c1a6c-4f1c-aa36-a70d-f2245f7rr342        1  334      yes  20150302
```

Comment: Thank you for the help Bill, I have two questions; On your first bullet point you mention " If no entry exists for id then defaultdict creates one and puts version in it. Are you saying that if a iteration through the csv finds a missing id, it will replace it with a arbitrary value? My second question is, in my example I used a id with just numbers though my actual id is a string numbers and letters. I tried used List in defaultDict but get a error saying too many values to unpack??

Comment: Q1: No, definitely not. I meant that, if there is no entry in the dictionary for the id then an entry is created for that id and then the value of version from the current line is put in that entry.
Q2: You should, please, show us your actual data so that we know precisely what you mean.

Comment: ah ok that makes more sense, revised data above

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure how you want your output to look like, but this might point you at least in the right direction, as long as you're not opposed to `pandas`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('rpm_inv.csv', header=True)

by_version = df.groupby('Version')

latest = by_version.max()
# To put it into a dictionary of {version:ID}
{v:row['ID'] for v, row in latest.iterrows()}
```

Comment: I am new to python but this is the second time I have seen reference to pandas. Is this something that has to be downloaded and imported in or does it come packaged with python 2.7? My ultimate output once I get the latest version of the record is to compare it to the original csv and find out what data has been deleted  in previous versions.

Comment: `pandas` can be installed quite simply by `pip install pandas` from your terminal / command prompt. It doesn't come packaged with python 2.7 (unless you installed python using a manager such as Anaconda). In any case, it is *highly* useful for any dataframe manipulations you might want to do in python